# Python, transposing a list and writing to a CSV file

Tags: python, list, csv

I need to write into a csv file using python and each iterator item should start in a new line.
So delimiter I am using is "\n".
After each list has been written,next list should write from next cell.
like below:

```
 lol = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

The csv will be like:

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

What I have tried:

```
file = open("test.csv", "wb")
fileWriter = csv.writer(file , delimiter='\n',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
spamWriter.writerow([1,2,3])
spamWriter = csv.writer(file , delimiter=',',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
spamWriter.writerow([4,5,6])
file.close()
```

Which results like below:

```
 1
 2
 3
 4 5 6
```

Using csv module how can I get output like below:

```
 1 4 
 2 5
 3 6
```

here space means comma in a csv file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without using zip, you could do this:

```
import csv

lol = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
item_length = len(lol[0])

with open('test.csv', 'wb') as test_file:
  file_writer = csv.writer(test_file)
  for i in range(item_length):
    file_writer.writerow([x[i] for x in lol])
```

This will output into test.csv:

```
1,4,7
2,5,8
3,6,9
```

Answer (score 11):

first transpose your input by using `zip()`

```
>>> zip(*lol)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

and after that just pass it to `csw.writer` e.g.

```
with open("test.csv", "wb") as f:
    fileWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in zip(*lol):
        fileWriter.writerow(row)
```

... which results to:

```
$ cat test.csv 
1,4
2,5
3,6
```

Comment: it writes with [ and ] character

Comment: I think you should just change the write attribute to `w` instead of `wb`, and then this answer will work perfectly..

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Python3 you need to open files in text format "wt", more over `csv` has `writerows` that can be used to write everything at once. here is an example:

```
data=[("test", "value1", "value2"), ("test2", "value3", "value4")]
with open('my.csv','wt') as out:
   csv_out=csv.writer(out)
   csv_out.writerows(data)
```

I've just noticed that the question ask how to transform the list, that is a separate step and here is how I would do it:

```
lol = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
data = zip(lol[0],lol[1])
```