# Save list of ordered tuples as CSV

Tags: python, csv, tuples

I have a list of tuples ordered by value. They are in the form `(name,count)` where
count is number of occurrences for each unique name.

I would like to take this list and transform it into CSV where each name is column header
and each value is column value of a single row.

Any suggestions how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your attempt at a solution. Folks will point you in the right direction. Hint: have a gander at the `csv` module in the standard-library.

Comment: Just write a string `output += myTuple[0] + ', ' + myTuple[1] + '\n'` in a for loop. When the loop is done write the `output` to a `*.csv` file.

Comment: just `import csv` and read the module docs, very simple. http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import csv

# note: If you use 'b' for the mode, you will get a TypeError
# under Python3. You can just use 'w' for Python 3

data=[('smith, bob',2),('carol',3),('ted',4),('alice',5)]

with open('ur file.csv','wb') as out:
    csv_out=csv.writer(out)
    csv_out.writerow(['name','num'])
    for row in data:
        csv_out.writerow(row)

    # You can also do csv_out.writerows(data) instead of the for loop
```

the output file will have:

```
name,num
"smith, bob",2
carol,3
ted,4
alice,5
```

Comment: Quite irregularly, writerow() puts quotation marks around SOME of the strings only. My raw data does not have quotation marks at all. Anything on that?

Comment: If you're on Windows, open the file with mode 'wb' to avoid getting a blank line between every row in the output.

Comment: In Python 3, use mode "w" instead of "wb", to avoid getting a TypeError. You can pass `newline=''`, which will take care of the redundant blank lines.

Comment: I'm getting this error, byte like object is required not str.

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb: That is from opening the file in binary mode `open('ur file.csv','wb')` The `b` in the mode with Python 3. Just remove the `b`  in the open mode.

Comment: ok but how do we get rid of that empty rows written? Seems open with 'w' you get extra newline every line

Answer (score 5):

[Python, transposing a list and writing to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573915/python-csv-file-writing)

```
import csv   
lol = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
item_length = len(lol[0])

with open('test.csv', 'wb') as test_file:
  file_writer = csv.writer(test_file)
  for i in range(item_length):
    file_writer.writerow([x[i] for x in lol])
```

output

```
1,4,7
2,5,8
3,6,9
```

Note that trying it in python 3 might give the error as mentioned in [TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in python and CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283178/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-in-python-and-csv).

Consider to use `with open('ur file.csv','w') as out:` for python 3.