# Can i import all data from sqlite file to a txt file python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a db file and in it, it has data that i want to save to a ordinary txt file. Or maybe can i get all data from the db file to a txt file? is there a way to do it. Thank you for answering

Comment: Can you show us what code you used?

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is a way! In python [import SQLite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) and select everything from the target table with a SELECT * FROM statement. This will return a list of tuples. Then refer [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15578485/12809492) from user dawg for how to write that list of tuples to a CSV file.

I would recommend saving data from a database in a CSV file instead of a TXT file, as a CSV file will preserve your rows and columns. Writing to a TXT file is a very similar method as dawg describes in the link provided, however.