# How to export igraph result in csv file in python?

Tags: python, igraph, sna

I wrote code below to show graph with igraph package, But I don't know How can I  export igraph result in csv file in python? and my another question is how can I add label?

```
import igraph as ig 
import pandas as pd
g=ig.Graph.TupleList(df.itertuples(index=False),directed=True)
ig.plot(g, target='graph.png', vertex_size=10, bbox=(0, 0, 500, 500))
```

Comment: `igraph` produces an image.  You can't save an image in a CSV, clearly.  What do you want in the CSV?

Comment: @TimRoberts Because I want to import that in gephi application I need csv file

Comment: @TimRoberts How can I export that with igraph, is there any way?

Comment: @TimRoberts May I ask you to help me How can I add label in image?

Comment: I don't know `genphi`.  What do you want the CSV to contain?  You have a list of tuples there in `g`, which you could wrote to CSV, but you'd need to know what the CSV has to contain.

Answer (score 3):

> Because I want to import that in gephi application I need csv file

Here is the list of formats that igraph can export to:

https://igraph.org/python/api/latest/igraph.Graph.html#write

This is the list of formats supported by Gephi:

https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/

Choose one that is common to both and use that. I would try GraphML first.

---

If you insist on CSV-like formats, NCOL comes closest. You can also use the `get_edgelist()` method to get the list of vertex pairs representing edges, then [export them using Python's own facilities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15578331/695132).