# Convert text file to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, csv

I have a text file and I want to convert it to a CSV.

**Input:**

```
Tabular Editor 2.15.3 (build 2.15.7767.23827)
--------------------------------
Loading model...
Running Best Practice Analyzer...
=================================
Measure [Internet Current Quarter Gross Profit Performance] violates rule "[DAX Expressions] Use the DIVIDE function for division"
Measure [Total Current Quarter Sales Performance] violates rule "[DAX Expressions] Avoid using the IFERROR function"
Relationship 'Employee'[SalesTerritoryKey] --> 'Sales Territory'[SalesTerritoryKey] violates rule "[DAX Expressions] Inactive relationships that are never activated"
Relationship 'Reseller Sales'[ShipDateKey] --> 'Date'[DateKey] violates rule "[DAX Expressions] Inactive relationships that are never activated"
=================================
```

**Output**:

| Object Type | Object | Rule Violated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Measure | [Internet Current Quarter Gross Profit Performance] | "[DAX Expressions] Use the DIVIDE function for division" |
| Measure | [Total Current Quarter Sales Performance] | "[DAX Expressions] Avoid using the IFERROR function" |
| Relationship | 'Employee'[SalesTerritoryKey] --> 'Sales Territory'[SalesTerritoryKey] | Inactive relationships that are never activated" |
| Relationship | 'Reseller Sales'[ShipDateKey] --> 'Date'[DateKey] | Inactive relationships that are never activated" |

Any help to achieve the above would be much appreciated.

I have a list of object types which can appear in first column

```
object_types = ["Calculated Column", "Calculated Table Column", "Calculated Table",
                "Calculated Group", "Calculated Item", "Culture", "Data Column",
                "Hierarchies", "KPIs", "Level", "Measure", "Model", "Model Roles",
                "Named Expressions", "Partitions", "Perspectives",
                "Provider Data Sources", "Relationship", "Structured Data Sources",
                "Table Permissions", "Tables", "Variations"]
```

We could also replace `" violates rule "` with a `","` to separate column 2 and 3.

Getting stuck on how to separate column 1 and 2.
How to find first and last line which begins with an `=`. This will help us determine the first row of data. Basically the data is in between the `==` sign lines.

Comment: "getting stuck on how to seperate column 1 and 2" Well, what is the rule that tells you where the separation should be? "how to find first and last line which begins with an =" Did you try looking at the lines one at a time, using a variable to remember how many times you have seen an `=` line, and using that value to decide what to do with each line?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I was initially trying  to use the following :

with open(path) as f:
    file = f.readLines()

and then basically do file[6:-1] to get the lines. of data, but I think there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex to match the various parts of the error messages, using `re.findall` to get a list of tuples containing the matching parts:

```py
text = '''
Tabular Editor 2.15.3 (build 2.15.7767.23827)
--------------------------------
Loading model...
Running Best Practice Analyzer...
=================================
Measure [Internet Current Quarter Gross Profit Performance] violates rule "[DAX Expressions] Use the DIVIDE function for division"
Measure [Total Current Quarter Sales Performance] violates rule "[DAX Expressions] Avoid using the IFERROR function"
Relationship 'Employee'[SalesTerritoryKey] --> 'Sales Territory'[SalesTerritoryKey] violates rule "[DAX Expressions] Inactive relationships that are never activated"
Relationship 'Reseller Sales'[ShipDateKey] --> 'Date'[DateKey] violates rule "[DAX Expressions] Inactive relationships that are never activated"
=================================
'''
object_types = ["Calculated Column", "Calculated Table Column", "Calculated Table", "Calculated Group", "Calculated Item", "Culture", "Data Column", "Hierarchies", "KPIs", "Level", "Measure", "Model", "Model Roles", "Named Expressions", "Partitions", "Perspectives", "Provider Data Sources", "Relationship", "Structured Data Sources", "Table Permissions", "Tables", "Variations"]
matches = re.findall(r'(' + '|'.join(object_types) + ')\s+(.*?)\s+violates rule\s+(.*)\n', text)
```

Output:

```
[
 ('Measure', '[Internet Current Quarter Gross Profit Performance]', '"[DAX Expressions] Use the DIVIDE function for division"'),
 ('Measure', '[Total Current Quarter Sales Performance]', '"[DAX Expressions] Avoid using the IFERROR function"'),
 ('Relationship', "'Employee'[SalesTerritoryKey] --> 'Sales Territory'[SalesTerritoryKey]", '"[DAX Expressions] Inactive relationships that are never activated"'),
 ('Relationship', "'Reseller Sales'[ShipDateKey] --> 'Date'[DateKey]", '"[DAX Expressions] Inactive relationships that are never activated"')
]
```

From there it's easy to write that out to a CSV file using for example the technique in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578331/save-list-of-ordered-tuples-as-csv).

Note that if you are reading the text file line by line, you should replace the `\n` at the end of the regex with `$`. For example:

```py
matches = []
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        matches.append(re.findall(r'(' + '|'.join(object_types) + ')\s+(.*?)\s+violates rule\s+(.*)$', line)
```

Comment: You can post-convert, for example `matches = [','.join(tup) for tup in matches]`

Comment: could you explain, how this works? 

matches = re.findall(r'(' + '|'.join(object_types) + ')\s+(.*?)\s+violates rule\s+(.*)\n', text)

Comment: basically we are forming a regex which looks for one of the object_types (using an alternation of all the values, captured in group 1), followed by some text until "violate rules" (captured in group 2), followed by whatever text remains until end of line (captured in group 3). You can print out the string to see what it looks like

Comment: thanks @Nick, I def need to read more about regex. This is a very elegant solution. I was able to use pandas to convert to csv after the tuple was created.

file = re.findall(r'(' + '|'.join(object_types) + ')\s+(.*?)\s+violates rule\s+(.*)\n', file)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(file, columns =['Object Type', 'Object', 'Vionation'])
df.to_csv('test.csv',index=False)