# Converting csv columns to rows with python

Tags: python, sql, csv, import-from-csv

I'm trying to create a list that will take data from `gradebook.csv` and change it to a different format.

gradebook.csv has columns like with data:

```
{ studentID , assignment1 , assignment2 , . . . assignmentN }
{ 2343      ,             ,   34.2      ,                   }
```

empty cells are assignments with no submission.  Cells with numbers represent grades.  This data will go into a list of the format:

```
{ studentID , assignmentid , grade }
{ 2343      , assignment2  , 34.2  }
```

the end result will be putting this data into a sql table in sql server 2012.  The code below does what I want, but only for the last row in `gradebook.csv`.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import csv

with open('gradebook.csv','rb') as g:
        gr=csv.reader(g)
        for row in gr:
            if row[0]=='User ID':
                pass
            else:
                studentid=row[0]
                individualassignments=[]
                everyone=[]
                for element in row[1:]:
                    if element=='':
                        pass
                    else:
                        individualassignments.append(element)

                individualassignments.append(studentid)
                everyone.append(individualassignments)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python, transposing a list and writing to a CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573915/python-transposing-a-list-and-writing-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate.  The other question involved writing to a csv file, while this question had a problem with loading the data into a list.

Comment: I feel like this is more than just transposing because I am taking one row and turning it into multiple rows for multiple grades. At least, that is my goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you clear out the `everyone` list (by setting `everyone=[]`) for each iteration of your outer `for` loop.  So only your last row in the csv file will be in the list.

To fix, you need to declare `everyone` outside of the loop

```
import csv

with open('gradebook.csv','rb') as g:
    gr=csv.reader(g)
    everyone=[]  # declare everyone here
    for row in gr:
        if row[0]=='User ID':
            pass
        else:
            studentid=row[0]
            individualassignments=[]               
            for element in row[1:]:
                if element=='':
                    pass
                else:
                    individualassignments.append(element)

            individualassignments.append(studentid)
            everyone.append(individualassignments)
```

Comment: This was the obvious answer that I missed on sight.