# Putting scraped data from beautifulsoup into a csv file

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to put the data I'm scraping from the website into a csv file, my first attempt was using scrapy but I couldn't get the syntax right. When I managed to do using beautifulsoup, I just don't know how to put it into a csv file.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://www.practo.com/tests/glycosylated-haemoglobin-blood/p?city=delhi"
page = requests.get(URL)
#print(page)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='root-app')
#print(results.prettify())
job_elems = results.find_all('div', class_='u-padrl--std')
#<h1 class="o-font-size--24 u-font-bold u-marginb--std">HbA1c Test</h1

for job_elem in job_elems:
    title_elem = job_elem.find('h1', class_='o-font-size--24 u-font-bold u-marginb--std')
    also_known = job_elem.find('span',class_="u-font-bold")
    cost = job_elem.find('div',class_="o-font-size--22 u-font-bold o-f-color--primary")
    what_test = job_elem.find('div',class_="c-markdown--unstyled")

    #test_prep = job_elem.find('div',class_="c-tabsection__content c-pp__accordion-item__content active")
    #temp = job_elem.find('p')
    print(title_elem.text)
    print(also_known.text)
    print(cost.text)
    print(what_test.text)
    #print(temp.text)
    #print(test_prep.text)
    print()

text_content = results.find_all('div',class_='c-markdown--unstyled')
# c-tabsection__content c-pp__accordion-item__content active
# c-tabsection c-pp__accordion-item u-br-rule u-padtb--std--half active
for item in text_content:
    prep = item.find('p')
    #,class_="c-tabsection__content c-pp__accordion-item__content active")
    print(prep.text)
    print('xxo')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, transposing a list and writing to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573915/python-transposing-a-list-and-writing-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: Unfortunately No, senor. @joshmeranda

Comment: looks like you want to write your CSV with the folloung columns: 1. title_elem 2. also_known 3. cost 4. what_text?

Comment: yes man exactly @SeyiDaniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# import the csv module 
import csv

URL = "https://www.practo.com/tests/glycosylated-haemoglobin-blood/p?city=delhi"
page = requests.get(URL)
#print(page)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='root-app')
#print(results.prettify())
job_elems = results.find_all('div', class_='u-padrl--std')
#<h1 class="o-font-size--24 u-font-bold u-marginb--std">HbA1c Test</h1
rows = []
fields = ['title_elem', 'also_known', 'cost', 'what_test']
filename = "myfile.csv"
for job_elem in job_elems:
    title_elem = job_elem.find('h1', class_='o-font-size--24 u-font-bold u-marginb--std').text.encode("utf-8")
    also_known = job_elem.find('span',class_="u-font-bold").text.encode("utf-8")
    cost = job_elem.find('div',class_="o-font-size--22 u-font-bold o-f-color--primary").text.encode("utf-8")
    what_test = job_elem.find('div',class_="c-markdown--unstyled").text.encode("utf-8")
    row = [title_elem, also_known, cost, what_test]
    rows.append(row)

with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile: 
    # creating a csv writer object 
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)   
    # writing the fields 
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)   
    # writing the data rows 
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)

text_content = results.find_all('div',class_='c-markdown--unstyled')
# c-tabsection__content c-pp__accordion-item__content active
# c-tabsection c-pp__accordion-item u-br-rule u-padtb--std--half active
for item in text_content:
    prep = item.find('p')
    #,class_="c-tabsection__content c-pp__accordion-item__content active")
    print(prep.text)
    print('xxo')
```

Comment: I hope the code comments provides you with enough guidance. I used the Python built-in CSV module. The `fields` variable represents the column headers, the result of each `job_elem` iteration is appended to the `row` list , which in turn is append to the `rows` list. Each `row` represents a row in you CSV.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) library.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("file.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write(row, column, element)

workbook.close()
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but i don't quite get it, i mean, could you edit this using my variables and program?